# Android Keyboard Replacement Web-view

Tags: javascript, android, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to embed a web-view into an android keyboard replacement app?

I have an interface written in javascript, and would like to embed that into an android keyboard replacement app. It will need to be able to detect touch events, and send text strings back to the native UI from the web-view.

I have searched google for this, but can not find any onformation on how to create web-view in keyboard replacement app.

---

#### EDIT: Created github project for boilerplate based on the on the answer from @ckozl

https://github.com/billymoon/javascript-android-keyboard-boilerplate

Comment: So lets get this straight, you have a lets say "HTML/JS" keybord in your webview. and want it to send data to your android device ?

Comment: in this case for the web view it did not seem to be necessary (per my experiment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In short. Not a great idea but technically feasible.
Let me walk you through a quick sample project, adapted from the SoftKeyboard sample included with the android SDK.  Now there are a number of other technical issues to tackle but this should provide you with a basic starting point....

For starters, lets create a basic layout to use as our keyboard:

***\res\layout\input.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <WebView
      android:id="@+id/myWebView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="600dp"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

this is required by android to accept our IME

***\res\xml\method.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  />
```

now onto our manifest
***\AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.example.android.softkeyboard">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:label="SoftKeyboard">

        <service 
            android:name="SoftKeyboard"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />      
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

obviously the `uses-sdk` and `user-permission` are up to the app and not required by this code (i'm not using any internet files here, but you could, i tested it and it worked...)

now define a simple keyboard
***\src...\SoftKeyboard.java:***

```
package com.example.android.softkeyboard;

import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private WebView myWebView = null;

    @Override 
    public View onCreateInputView() {

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input, null);
        myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "android");

        return view;
    }

    private Object jsInterface = new Object() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void sendKeys() {
            getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText("how do ya like me now?", 1);
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onWindowShown() {

        super.onWindowShown();      
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/keyboard_test.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {}

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {}

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {}

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {}

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {}

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {}

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {}

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {}

}
```

here we basically create a webview then populate it from a asset file and bind a simple interface to it after enabling javascript

here's the asset html:
***\assets\keyboard_test.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<style>
button {

    display:block;
    margin:300px auto;
    width:400px;
    padding:60px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="android.sendKeys()">yeah buddy!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

and that's it, run it and you'll get a keyboard with a single button and when you push it the javascript will send text into the input composer...

hope that helps -ck

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer. I have not checked the code yet, but it looks like it is exactly what I need. Thanks for providing full comments/demo. I will probably put this up as a working demo on github so other people can use it as a base.

Comment: Besides performance concerns (which I am well aware of), are there any other issues which make my plan "Not a great idea"?

Comment: Performance is the main reason, keyboards are supposed to be light weight with very simple layouts (meaning the xml layout should be lacking in complexity, not the keyboard layout itself) so that they load fast and are very responsive. My experience with `WebView` is that it is volatile, slow and heavy. I made an app that actually had it's own keyboard that controlled drawing on a `<canvas>` (though the keyboard was built into the app, not a popup type) and when it was built inside the `WebView` it was unresponsive and clunky feeling.  [....cont....]

Comment: Once the keyboard portion of the app was re-implemented using the native UI constructs (java/xml) it felt 10x more responsive and snappy.  Just a better UX in general.  However maybe ICS and the eventual integration with Chrome will address some of these concerns -ck

Comment: I had issues with canvas myself. It would be great if it worked well, but seems a bit heavy. I am making a fairly simple interface which just swaps a few images around and detects touch events which seems to be working ok. You will be happy to know it is all implemented and working as expected, even with my own javascript code. Thanks a whole lot for this answer, I was lost without it.

Comment: np, if you end up publishing the app or open the source up on github or something, you'll have to come back here and share the link because I can't deny saying that I am curious as to what your going to produce with this... And the `<canvas>` wasn't slow (unless you turned on hardware acceleration, ironic right?), there was just a perceivable lag between touch and touch event on normal DOM elements... -ck

Comment: Unfortunately the project I am working on can not be open source, but I am planning to combine your answer, into the google SoftKeyboard demo, and add a little documentation so people can use that as a boilerplate for their own javascript based keyboards. I will put that on github, and share the link here. Hopefully people will then add to the boilerplate as there are a lot of intricate details to writing keyboard apps. I might make a morse code keyboard on there so people can see how it works.

Comment: Github repo as requested: https://github.com/billymoon/javascript-android-keyboard-boilerplate

Comment: Is this necessary: `implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener`?

Comment: @agksmehx that's the IME's interface for key events and gestures, so i guess the answer to your question is: maybe, it depends on what you're doing, but in general i don't believe it to be required for input method to be accepted as such... you could always test and see what happens.... -ck